# Using a swig wrapped c++ library with go

Tags: c++, go, swig

I have managed to successfully wrap a large `C++` [library](https://github.com/LibRaw/LibRaw/tree/master) with `SWIG`. I published the [module](https://github.com/MRHT-SRProject/LibRawGo/tree/master/librawgo) and can install it okay, but when I go to build it I get a ton of `undefined reference` errors to the functions contained within the generated `c` file.

I placed the generated `so` lib file in my system lib directory, and placed the header files from the library into my system include directory, but this has not solved the problem. I am guessing that I need a header file for wrapped `c` file as well so the interpreter can know what's in the `so` file, but given that `SWIG` didn't generate one, I don't know if I am missing anything else. I'm going to try to write my own header file to see if that resolves the errors, but even if it does, shouldn't that be something that `SWIG` would do automatically?

My source files are below

```
/** file: golibraw.i **/
%module librawgo
%{
#define LIBRAW_LIBRARY_BUILD
/* Put headers and other declarations here */
#include "libraw/libraw.h"
#include "libraw/libraw_alloc.h"
#include "libraw/libraw_const.h"
#include "libraw/libraw_datastream.h"
#include "libraw/libraw_internal.h"
#include "libraw/libraw_types.h"
#include "libraw/libraw_version.h"
%}

%include "libraw/libraw.h"
%include "libraw/libraw_alloc.h"
%include "libraw/libraw_const.h"
%include "libraw/libraw_datastream.h"
%include "libraw/libraw_internal.h"
%include "libraw/libraw_types.h"
%include "libraw/libraw_version.h"
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

if ( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory and run CMake from there. You may need to remove CMakeCache.txt." )
endif()

find_package(SWIG 4.0 COMPONENTS python OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS go)
if(SWIG_FOUND)
  message("SWIG found: ${SWIG_EXECUTABLE}")
  include (UseSWIG)
  if(NOT SWIG_go_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "SWIG go bindings cannot be generated")
  endif()
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "SWIG NOT FOUND")
endif()

set(PROJECT_NAME librawgo)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

SET (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/librawgo
        CACHE PATH
        "Single Directory for all"
    )

find_program( CLANG_TIDY NAMES clang-tidy)



set(${PROJECT_NAME}_sources ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/librawgo.i )


swig_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} TYPE SHARED LANGUAGE go SOURCES ${${PROJECT_NAME}_sources})


if(CLANG_TIDY)
set_property(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTY CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${CLANG_TIDY}")
endif()

    set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY SWIG_COMPILE_OPTIONS -go -intgosize 64 -cpperraswarn)
    set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES TRUE)
    set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
    set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Go compiler has no idea about the library `librawgo.so`.

Put the following line to the top of the `C` comment in `librawgo.go`:

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L<path/to/dir/with/librawgo.so> -lrawgo -lraw
```

This instruction tells the compiler to add this line to the linker flags.

Sorry, I don't know how to modify your CMake and SWIG settings to generate this line automatically.